# Is editing answers to link to a tutorial on your own website/blog tolerated?

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits, self-promotion

I've been reviewing a few [Suggested Edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1734814) this morning on SO and I've noticed that one guy has gone through a couple of answers involving "StartSSL", editing them to include:

> Here is how to get a free SSL certificate with StartSSL: http://[user's own blog].org/2013/03/17/get-a-free-ssl-certificate-with-startssl/.

The blog in question does indeed feature a valid tutorial. Is this tolerated or should these edits be rejected? For now I've simply skipped them as I wasn't too sure.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1734812
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1734814

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be rejected, because the linked content *could* not match the intention of the post's original author.

He should have posted it in a separate answer, and disclosed his affiliation with the blog.

Comment: Without any substantive instructions besides the link, it wouldn't be appropriate as another answer either. (It would be a link-only answer.)

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: Note: These questions should also be closed. (Deleting them would also remove the reputation he got from the bad approvals.) ;)